# What are the benefits of having a hero with video background?

Tags: video

I am a web developer and noticed the hero background video trending of the moment. As I try and build my websites with performance in mind I have been struggling with this new trend.

I would like to have a list of pros and understand how it reflects on the user experience. How do it's benefits outweighs the loss in performance.

Answer (score 1):

This blog [Justinmind: 10 inspiring hero image websites](https://www.justinmind.com/blog/10-inspiring-hero-image-websites/) says

> In fact, statistics shared by Forbes show that embedding a hero background video can help boost your conversion rates by 80% and influence a customer’s purchasing decision by 90%.

Unfortunately, there's no Forbes link.

And even more unfortunately, I don't like hero video backgrounds at all. Too distracting for me personally.

Comment: That statistic sounds like complete bunk anyway.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/kateharrison/2018/04/06/what-you-really-need-to-know-about-explainer-videos/#47124ed06f02 think this is the article. Justinmind misinterpreted the forbes article big time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The forbes link above writes about explainer videos. The ones I am working on are muted and a collection of short scenes. 
I don't dislike them and I see that they can make the website (company) look more professional, which will increase its trustworthiness.
I believe in cases of videos with collection of scenes and muted it could last no more than 10 secs. Who thinks someone would stop and stare at a muted video for longer than that? Being short it achieve the trustworthiness, attracted the user and did not damage the loading performance. Am I wrong/missing smthing?

Comment: Here is an article that evaluates the usage of hero video for landing pages. Worth reading.
`"A 5-10 second video loop should be enough time to get the point across without sacrificing quick load time."`
https://unbounce.com/landing-pages/do-video-backgrounds-help-or-hurt-conversions/

Comment: Here is another, more focused on homepage. https://matttanguay.com/blog/pros-and-cons-of-a-homepage-background-video/

Comment: @stemon Yes the forbes link writes about explainer videos but they mention the same stats (80% conversion increase) as the Justinmind article. So I think, Justinmind used those stats of 'explainer video' to 'proof' their point on hero video.